# Failed to initialize an array of hexadecimal numbers: "Keyword does not name a type"

Tags: arrays, vb.net, initialization

I am trying to initialize hexadecimal numbers array like that:

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
        Dim someArray As Variant
        someArray = Array(&H11, &H22, &H33)
        
    End Sub
End Module
```

I am using [this](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_vb_compiler) website to run it and I get the error:

```
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943 (Mono 4.6 - tarball)
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.
/home/main.vb (11,29) : error VBNC30180: Keyword does not name a type.
/home/main.vb (12,14): Compiler error around this location, the compiler hasn't implemented the error message, nor error recovery, so the compiler will probably crash soon.
  at vbnc.Helper.ErrorRecoveryNotImplemented (vbnc.Span Location) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseVariableDeclarator (vbnc.ParsedObject Parent, vbnc.Modifiers Modifiers, vbnc.ParseAttributableInfo Info, System.Collections.IList result, System.Boolean local) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseLocalVariableDeclarator (vbnc.ParsedObject Parent, vbnc.Modifiers Modifiers, vbnc.ParseAttributableInfo Info) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseLocalVariableDeclarators (vbnc.ParsedObject Parent, vbnc.Modifiers Modifiers, vbnc.ParseAttributableInfo Info) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseLocalDeclarationStatement (vbnc.CodeBlock Parent) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseCodeBlock (vbnc.ParsedObject Parent, System.Boolean IsOneLiner) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseSubDeclaration (vbnc.TypeDeclaration Parent, vbnc.ParseAttributableInfo Info) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseTypeMembers (vbnc.TypeDeclaration Parent) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseModuleDeclaration (vbnc.ParsedObject Parent, vbnc.Attributes Attributes, System.String Namespace) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseTypeDeclaration (vbnc.ParsedObject Parent, vbnc.Attributes Attributes, System.String Namespace) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseAssemblyMembers (vbnc.AssemblyDeclaration Parent, System.String RootNamespace) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.ParseAssemblyDeclaration (System.String RootNamespace, vbnc.AssemblyDeclaration assembly) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Parser.Parse (System.String RootNamespace, vbnc.AssemblyDeclaration assembly) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Compiler.Compile_Parse () [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Compiler.Compile () [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Compiler.Compile (System.String[] CommandLine) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
  at vbnc.Main.Main (System.String[] CmdArgs) [0x00000] in <cd55155bc3b542a49b0b2bb7e08ded22>:0 
There were 1 errors and 0 warnings.
Compilation took 00:00:02.3128040
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Variant` is not a data type in VB.NET. VBA is not VB.NET.

Comment: For that `vb.net` is not the same as `vba`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a hexadecimal number per se in VB.NET. Hexadecimal is simply a way to represent literal values of an integral type, i.e. `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer` or `Long`. If you want an array of `Integer` values then that's what you need to create:

```vb
Dim someArray As Integer() = {&H11, &H22, &H33}
```

With `Option Infer On`, which it is by default, you can allow the type to be inferred too:

```vb
Dim someArray = {&H11, &H22, &H33}
```

In both cases, the variable now refers to an array containing the values 17, 34 and 51. They are just numbers, not hexadecimal numbers. You could use decimal or octal literals to get the exactly same array. Where hexadecimal numbers are often most useful is to represent `Byte` values, where two digits can represent the full range of values from 0 to 255:

```vb
Dim someArray As Byte() = {&H11, &H22, &H33}
```

In that case, you would need to be explicit with the type of the array as type inference would yield an `Integer` array. To use type inference, you'd have to go the more verbose, and therefore pointless, route:

```vb
Dim someArray = {CByte(&H11), CByte(&H22), CByte(&H33)}
```